# UITapGestureRecognizer conflicting with CCButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've looked around on Stack for solutions to this and found quite a few results, but I'm still unable to fix my problem, mainly because I'm working on a CCNode opposed to some UIView.

Anyways, my CCButton works find without the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, but when I implement it, it overrides my button press. Obviously I would like to avoid this.

My code is below. My swipe gestures work perfectly, but the tap interferes with my button. I'm not sure if I'm adding the gesture recognizer to the wrong view, because `- (BOOL)gesturerecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch` never runs, which is where I would put in my exception. If anyone can give me some code/ideas on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
-(void)didLoadFromCCB   

    UITapGestureRecognizer * gridTapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gridTapped)];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:gridTapped];

    //this works totally fine
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeLeft= [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
}


-(void)gridTapped {
    //this works!
    CCLOG(@"Grid tapped");
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    //This never runs
    CCLOG(@"gesture recognized");
    if ((touch.view == mainMenuButton)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't have much time for cocos2d but i guess you should try: if(gestureRecognizer == gridTapped) { //do smt } else if (gestureRecognizer == swipeLeft) { //do smt }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the UITapGestureRecognizer delegate:

```
gridTapped.delegate = self;
```

You'll need to declare the VC class as implementing `<UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

Comment: Thanks, this essentially worked, except for it created another bug somewhere else. Basically I clicked my main menu button successfully, went back to the main menu, then clicked my play button to return to this screen and play the game, but then it bugged out on my main.m file, where it says int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: It says Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 1, address = 0xe000000c)

Comment: No idea, but it sounds like a different question.  Try turning adding an exception breakpoint.